# Rust how to handle error sending message to disconnected client

Tags: rust, udp, rust-tokio

Good morning people! I'm starting in the Rust world and would like to ask for help.

In the code below I am simulating sending to a client that has disconnected, the program breaks when I try to send a message to a client that is no longer connected. how to treat so that the program does not break?

the match command doesn't even work

> Error: Os { code: 10054, kind: ConnectionReset, message: "Forced cancellation
> from an existing connection by the remote host." }

```
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use std::io;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let sock = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").await?;
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    loop {
        let (len, addr) = sock.recv_from(&mut buf).await?;
        println!("{:?} bytes received from {:?}", len, addr);

        let len = sock.send_to(&buf[..len], addr).await?;
        println!("{:?} bytes sent", len);

        match sock.send_to(&buf, "127.0.0.1:23451").await
        {
            Result::Ok(_len) => {
                println!("{:?} bytes sent", _len);
            }
            Result::Err(_) => {
                println!("a error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I don't pass a valid address, I can get the error with match, but passing a valid address from a user that disconnected from the error and I can't get the match

[image]

---

**Solution** tks Guys!

```
use std::io;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let sock = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").await?;
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    loop {
        match sock.recv_from(&mut buf).await {
            Result::Ok(data) => {
                let (len, addr) = data;
                println!("{:?} bytes received from {:?}", len, addr);

                let len = sock.send_to(&buf[..len], addr).await?;
                println!("{:?} bytes sent", len);
            }
            Result::Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e);
            }
        }

        // SEND MESAGE TO USER DISCONECTED
        match sock.send_to(&buf, "127.0.0.1:23451").await {
            Result::Ok(_len) => {
                println!("{:?} bytes sent", _len);
            }
            Result::Err(_) => {
                println!("a error 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are the first "bytes received" and "bytes sent" messages printed?

Comment: this is an example echo from the rust documentation.  what I did was send the message to a client that is not connected to simulate an error.  I'm making a game server that I want to send message to players close to me but not all players so I tested sending message to a player who may have disconnected

Comment: The `?` operator is an early-exit. If you don't want to exit on error, then you'd need to handle that error as well (either with `match`, `if`, or other method)

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Reddit post, it is possible the error is detected during `recv_from` that follows the `send_to`, where error is not handled.

> Damnit, it was something simple, as always. So, the send operation obviously causes the error, but it was not emitted until a subsequent call to recv_from(). Thank you!

https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/a2hh6n/cannot_handle_os_error_while_using_udpsocket/

Comment: thanks but still not the solution, this is such a banal thing that it should be automatic, if it is not connected it ignores the sending...

Comment: @ClaudioSilva I cannot reproduce your problem here but its on Linux

Comment: Problem solved! thank you very much @coredump ! I'll edit the post to put the solution!